# Getting nUnit selected categories programmatically

Tags: c#, nunit

Is there a way of programatically getting the selected test categories while executing a test? something in the lines of
TestContext.Properties["_SELECTCATEGORIES"]

basically i've got test cases which load the test data from a db and as i've got a lot of tests the project is taking a long time to load. Im trying to find a way of having the testCaseSources returning nothing if the category is not selected

Comment: what do you mean with test categories?

Comment: I mean the categories selected in the nunit gui or console in the included categories for execution

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATED**

There does not appear to be any straightforward method for identifying or loading selected categories in an NUnit test assembly within the *NUnit Framework* itself..

Using reflection, you could perhaps scan the property `Categories` in classes decorated with `TestAttribute` or `TestFixtureAttribute`. By matching these categories with the one(s) you want to load, you could be able to filter out which tests to load before loading.

And then there is the `TestContext.Test.Properties` key `_CATEGORIES` (available in NUnit 2.5.7 and later):

```
[Test]
[Category("Hello")]
public void TestCategory()
{
  Assert.IsTrue(((ArrayList)TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Properties["_CATEGORIES"]).Contains("Hello"));
}
```

Some more to read on the `TestContext` class can be found [here](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/TestContext). Of course, to solve the problem with this approach would require you to load the entire test assembly and loop over all test cases in beforehand, which is obviously undesirable in your scenario.

Comment: Not quite. The ["_CATEGORIES"] returns the categories decorating the test, what i need is the categories selected in the nunit gui or console to execute

Comment: @z0c Perhaps not a very encouraging update, but at least I have tried to adapt my answer to better respond to your question.

Comment: in the "here" link in this answer, I get an "Account Suspended" message. Please provide a new link.

Comment: Thanks @AndersGustafsson

Answer (score 0):

var testCategory = (string)TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Properties["Category"].First();

If trying to read it from a test fixture (not the test method) then put the code in the [OneTimeSetUp]